# how to extract (plot) the hidden units/softmax (features) from a autoencoder using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, stacked, mnist, autoencoder, softmax

I'm new with ML, and I'm using tensorflow.
I want to see the features of my autoencoder, but I don't know how to extract(see) the hidden units.
could someone help me?

I made my own dataset, but the original code is with MNIST:
https://jmetzen.github.io/2015-11-27/vae.html

I added a layer of hidden units to transform it to Stacked AE.. (I don't know if it became stacked, but worked)

my AE: https://github.com/Snowedze/Autoencoder.git

Comment: Do you just want to extract the weights of the hidden units or see there activation?

Comment: I want to see there activation